# Naftiridine hydrogenation

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction, heterocyclic-compounds

I was reading an article about the synthesis of 1,2,3,4 tetrahydronaphtyridine and I found this image. [image]
I don't understand why the major product of hydrogenation is the less substituted and not the most. I thought that with an alkyl chains there was more negative density on the ring and so hydrogenations was most likely to happen in that ring.

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE. How major is the major isomer? What is "negative density"? The unsubstituted ring is less hindered favoring absorption on the catalyst surface. The alkyl group provides a steric factor and likely some hyperconjugation stabilization.

Comment: Another interesting question is the distribution of 3 and its isomer different in acid vs base.? I'd expect more 3 in base than acid.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a reference to the synthesis and a description of the conditions used for the hydrogenation step